# How to create Settings with toolbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, settings, preferencefragment

I have a Settings Preference screen.It has a ListPreference and a CheckBoxPreference. I want to change my app's date format when I choose an item of ListPreference. Also, by the CheckBoxPreference I want to show/hide notification on the status bar. Can anyone tell what I have to do to achieve that.

Also, how can I add a toolbar to the preference screen?  I am stuck here. Please help. Thanks in advance. 
I am stuck here. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
    String dateFormat = "dd - MM - yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
    tv_Current_Date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar_now.getTime()));
    String short_weekday = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays()[day_of_current_week];
    tv_Current_weekday.setText(short_weekday);
    til_Current_Date.setError(null);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent_settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_settings);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked on settings action menu.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

NotificationManager mNotifyManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean notifyEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_cb_notification", true);
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notifyEnabled) {
        //Show notification
        showNotification();
    }
    else {
        //Hide notification
        hideNotification();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_cb_notification", false);
        if (isChecked) {
            //Show notification
            showNotification();
        }
        else {
            //Hide notification
            hideNotification();
        }

}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    }
}

//Method to show notification
public void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(SettingsActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("My Application")
                    .setSubText("Tap to start");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(SettingsActivity.this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //System.currentTimeMillis();
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotifyManager.notify(1, notification);
}

//Method to hide notification
public void hideNotification() {
    mNotifyManager.cancel(1);
}
```

}

[Settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63pQd.jpg)

Comment: how are you unable to control it?

Answer (score 0):

for adding toolbar you just need to use the coordinator layout in the layout file of your activity. Preference activity has simple layout like others and you just inflate preference fragments inside a container.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that. I am a newbie to this field.@Umar

Answer (score 0):

add appcompact design support library to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Add toolbar.xml to your layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then include toolbar in your activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/TextDimTop"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then you need to set up it in your activity

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and then by using onCreateOptionsMenu you can add settings menu  on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response@ysl. I already have a toolbar in my MainActivity and other activity. Problem is when I go to settings screen by clicking "Settings" in option menu only there is no toolbar. Now as you stated above if I include the toolbar.xml in my activity_main.xml the my previous toolbar comtaining the app name is gone and the Settings toolbar takes its position

Comment: If you are using Activity to display setting then its normal behavior if you want to show toolbar for all screen then go with fragments

Comment: I am using fragment for settings. I have posted my settingsactivity.java class. Please see it and tell what I have to do

Comment: In this case you have to include toolbar to your SettingsActivity or you you can redirect user to settingsFragment instead of SettingActivity

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you please help?

Comment: replace this Intent intent_settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_settings); to   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();   and in mainactivity use frame layout as you are using in your settingactivity

Comment: If I replace the intent with the fragment then when I click on settings then this fragment floats over my previous main activity

Comment: what ever is the code of your main activity that needs to in fragment which will be shown by default when you launch your app and when you want to show your settings fragment you  need to replace your main fragment with settingfragment